# Where to draw the line - is it possible to love LINQ too much?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I recently found LINQ and love it.  I find lots of occasions where use of it is so much more expressive than the longhand version but a colleague passed a comment about me abusing this technology which now has me second guessing myself.  It is my perspective that if a technology works efficiently and the code is elegant then why not use it?  Is that wrong?  I could spend extra time writing out processes "longhand" and while the resulting code may be a few ms faster, it's 2-3 times more code and therefore 2-3 times more chance that there may be bugs.

Is my view wrong?  *Should* I be writing my code out longhand rather than using LINQ?  Isn't this what LINQ was designed for?

Edit: I was speaking about LINQ to objects, I don't use LINQ to XML so much and I have used LINQ to SQL but I'm not so enamoured with those flavours as LINQ to objects.

Comment: you don't specify which flavor....LINQ to Objects? LINQ to XML? LINQ to SQL?  The first two I agree with you, the last one I don't use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have to agree with your view - if it's more efficient to write and elegant then what's a few milliseconds.  Writing extra code gives more room for bugs to creep in and it's extra code that needs to be tested and most of all it's extra code to maintain.  Think about the guy who's going to come in behind you and maintain your code - they'll thank you for writing elegant easy to read code long before they thank you for writing code that's a few ms faster!

Beware though, this cost of a few ms could be significant when you take the bigger picture into account.  If that few milliseconds is part of a loop of thousands of repetitions, then the milliseconds add up fast.

Comment: That's what I thought too.  My perspective is that it's only abuse if you're going out of your way to find reasons to use it in the wrong places

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can love LINQ too much - [Single Statement LINQ RayTracer](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2007/Nov-16.html)

Where do you draw the line? I'd say use LINQ as much as it makes the code simpler and easier to read.

The moment the LINQ version becomes more difficult to understand then the non-LINQ version it's time to swap, and vice versa. EDIT: This mainly applies to LINQ-To-Objects as the other LINQ flavours have their own benefits.

Comment: My god that LINQ example is ridiculous!!! I have to say that it's unlikely that I'll ever have the time to decipher all that.  I guess that crosses the line of sanity.

Comment: draw the line? raytracer? I get this joke.

Comment: Haha Nicholas, good one!
And I agree, it is a ridiculous example, but I think it also is a very interesting challenge to understand what and how it does.

Comment: Plus one for time to swap. As cool as linq is (Mostly referring to its functional style), there maybe a scalability line in terms of performance, readability, etc. When linq approaching the line, be cautious, when it crosses it, swap.

Answer (score 8):

Its not possible to love Linq to Objects too much, it's a freaking awesome technology !

But seriously, anything that makes your code simple to read, simple to maintain and does the job it was intended for, then you would be silly not to use it as much as you can.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ's supposed to be used to make filtering, sorting, aggregating and manipulating data from various sources as intuitive and expressive as possible. I'd say, use it wherever you feel it's the tidiest, most expressive and most natural syntax for doing what it is you're trying to do, and don't feel guilty about it.

*If you start humping the documentation, then it may be time to reconsider your position.*

Comment: lol - yeah, if I ever start getting hot flushes when I think about programming I'll take a vacation :P

Comment: So the documentation should be on top?

Comment: I think documentation is more like a programmers Girlfriend or wife - In theory it should always come first, but in reality it mostly gets forgotten about until harshly reminded that it needs to be remembered!

Answer (score 5):

It's cases like these where it's important to remember the golden rules of optimization:

1. Don't Do It
2. For Experts: Don't do it yet

You should absolutely **not** worry about "abusing" linq unless you can indentify it explicitly as the cause of a performance problem

Comment: I don't like this. I There is a reasonable view that goes something like "Don't prematurely go out of your way to optimize." However, this attitude seems to be more like "make it as slow as you know how to code it fast."  If one was to take this seriously, one would always choose the naive approach.

Answer (score 5):

Like anything, it can be abused. As long as you stay away from obvious poor decisions such as

```
var v = List.Where(...);
for(int i = 0; i < v.Count(); i++)
{...}
```

and understand how differed execution works, then it is most likely not going to be much slower than the longhand way. According to Anders Hejlsburg (C# architect), the C# compiler is not particularly good at optimizing loops, however it is getting much better at optimizing and parallelizing expression trees. In time, it may be more effective than a loop. The List<>'s ForEach version is actually as fast as a for loop, although I can't find the link that proves that.

P.S. My personal favorite is ForEach<>'s lesser known cousin IndexedForEach (utilizing extension methods)

```
List.IndexedForEach( (p,i) => 
 {
     if(i != 3)
        p.DoSomething(i);
 };
```

Comment: what do you mean by "differed execution"?

Comment: Hi Bob, Many of the LINQ statements don't actually do anything until you try and use them. For instance, List.Where() will not be evaluated until Count() is called. However, calling count will evaluate the statement each loop iteration, so the Linq statement is evaluated each loop iteration

Comment: Oh - deferred...yeah, I follow now.  I thought I'd missed some concept called "differed" execution.

Comment: To have the var v statement execute immediately, you can call ToList<> or ToArray<>

Comment: it's called differed in the O'Rielly LINQ book and on the internet. I prefer deferred also

Comment: It *would* make understanding and communication concepts easier if they used the correct English :P

Comment: Just type "differed execution" into Google.  This actually saw print.  That's just embarrassing.

Comment: Its everywhere, I think they really meant to call it that...

Comment: A Google of "deferred execution": top answer is MSDN leading me to conclude that Microsoft (a well respected authority on .NET[?]) meant it to be understood as such.  It *is* embarassing that Apress (who appears to be the originator of the term *differed execution*) made such an obvious mistake...

Answer (score 4):

LINQ can be like art. Keep using it to make the code beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

You're answering your own question by talking about writing 2-3 times more code for a few ms of performance. I mean, if your problem domain requires that speedup then yes, if not probably not. However, is it really only a few ms of performance or is it > 5% or > 10%. This is a value judgement based on the individual case.

Comment: That's a fair point I suppose - if you're to increase each iteration of a cycle by a few ms then it would decrease performance by some magnitude - however in the case of large processing loops I would likely code for performance ahead of elegance if it meant a significant difference

Answer (score 0):

Where to draw the line?

Well, we already know that it is a bad idea to implement your own [quicksort in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185072/learning-linq-quicksort), at least compared to just using linq's orderby.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using LINQ has speed up my development and made it easier to avoid stupid mistakes that loops can introduce.  I have had instances where the performance of LINQ was poor, but that was when I was using it to things like fetch data for an excel file from a tree structure that had millions of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

While I see how there is a point of view that LINQ might make a statement harder to read, I think it is far outweighed by the fact that my methods are now strictly related to the problems that they are solving and not spending time either including lookup loops or cluttering classes with dedicated lookup functions.

It took a little while to get used to doing things with LINQ, since looping lookups, and the like, have been the main option for so long.  I look at LINQ as just being another type of syntactic sugar that can do the same task in a more elegant way.  Right now, I am still avoiding it in processing-heavy mission critical code - but that is just until the performance improves as LINQ evolves.

Answer (score 0):

My only concern about LINQ is with its implementation of joins.

As I determined when trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387772/does-linq-use-datarelations-to-optimize-joins) (and it's confirmed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387080.aspx)), the code LINQ generates to perform joins is (necessarily, I guess) naive:  for each item in the list, the join performs a linear search through the joined list to find matches.

Adding a join to a LINQ query essentially turns a linear-time algorithm into a quadratic-time algorithm.  Even if you think premature optimization is the root of all evil, the jump from O(n) to O(n^2) should give you pause.  (It's O(n^3) if you join through a joined item to another collection, too.)

It's relatively easy to work around this.  For instance, this query:

```
var list = from pr in parentTable.AsEnumerable()
join cr in childTable.AsEnumerable() on cr.Field<int>("ParentID") equals pr.Field<int>("ID")
where pr.Field<string>("Value") == "foo"
select cr;
```

is analogous to how you'd join two tables in SQL Server.  But it's terribly inefficient in LINQ:  for every parent row that the `where` clause returns, the query scans the entire child table.  (Even if you're joining on an unindexed field, SQL Server will build a hashtable to speed up the join if it can.  That's a little outside LINQ's pay grade.)

This query, however:

```
string fk = "FK_ChildTable_ParentTable";
var list = from cr in childTable.AsEnumerable()
where cr.GetParentRow(fk).Field<string>("Value") == "foo"
select cr;
```

produces the same result, but it scans the child table once only.

If you're using LINQ to objects, the same issues apply:  if you want to join two collections of any significant size, you're probably going to need to consider implementing a more efficient method to find the joined object, e.g.:

```
Dictionary<Foo, Bar> map = buildMap(foos, bars);
var list = from Foo f in foos
where map[f].baz == "bat"
select f;
```

Comment: This is completely untrue. LINQ's join operator loads all the elements in the inner sequence into an efficient hashtable-based lookup.

Your particular example is mildly inefficent in that you're filtering AFTER joining (rather than before) but the join itself is totally efficient.